Find no of digits of a number with only arithmetics
I want to find no of digits of a number using only maths, it seems greatest integer of log of that num with base 10 gives numbers like 1.99, 2.37, 72.5 and greatest integer of them like 2, 3, 73 is the no of digits, how do you find greatest integer and log in assembly x86 32 bits I want the number in integer.
As I said above I tried all.

Count how many times you can divide the number by 10 before it becomes zero.  We can't show you any specific code for that because we have no idea what CPU you're writing for.

What architecture are you programming for?

Related: How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string) loops a number of times equal to the number of decimal digits of an integer.  And links some more efficient algorithms such as a table of numbers to compare to.  (There aren't that many different powers of 10 that fit in 32 bits).

Other possible tricks include a bit-scan for the highest set bit (x86 bsr or lzcnt) and index a table of values to compare to, since some ranges of numbers with the same leading bit span across an order of magnitude.  (But at most two decimal-length possibilities for each MSB position, so only lzcnt / mov or lea using the index / compare / add or adc or something.)

How do I determine the number of digits of an integer in C? includes a bit-scan answer showing how it compiles to x86-64 asm (using bsr).  There are other answers showing other algorithms that just use math, no bit-manipulation, if you want to limit yourself to that.

Nasm x86 assembly 32 bits in linux, is that what u mean?
